# Footer with 4 list columns issue

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at CSS and I'm trying to do a footer with 4 lists and I want the lists to be one beside the other and I want each list in vertically. I'm trying to do that with html below but I´m not having the right results.
I got my first left list and related links well at left but the others lists do not appear next to the first; they appear below them.
Can you give me some help understanding what I'm doing wrong?
My fiddle to see better what is happening: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/V4MZC/)

My HTML:

```
<footer id="footer-container">

                <section id="footer1">

                <h1>LIST 1</h1>
                  <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 4</a></li>
                 </ul>


                 <h1>LIST 2</h1>
                  <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 4</a></li>
                 </ul>

                  <h1>LIST 3</h1>
                  <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 4</a></li>
                 </ul>

                  <h1>LIST 4</h1>
                  <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link Util 4</a></li>
                 </ul>
     </section>
    </footer>
```

My css:

```
#footer-container
{
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:#1d282e; 
    margin-top:15px; 
    bottom:0;

}

#footer1
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto auto;
    height:280px; 
}

#footer1 h1
{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
    font-family:'bariol_boldbold';
    color:#fff; 
    width:210px;
    float:left; 
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-right:30px;
 }

#footer1 ul 
    {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header tags are breaking it due to their default styling for a beginning. 
Also, lists are displayed vertically by default as well.

Move your Headings into the list, remove the header tags and style them with 'span' tags instead.
Then float your lists so they appear side by side as intended.

Click the link for an explaination in code

[jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/u75A6/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/u75A6/5/)

HTML

```
         <ul>
           <li><span class="listHeadStyle">List 1</span></li>   
           <li><a href="#">Link Util 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link Util 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link Util 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link Util 4</a></li>
         </ul>
```

CSS

```
#footer1 ul 
{
list-style:none;
display:block;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also find other solution with put each <ul> inside a div. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/u75A6/6/

Answer (score 0):

the other answer is very good solution. another option is to just wrap each block in a div, and float those divs left like this:

```
<footer id="footer-container">
       <section id="footer1">

            <div class="footerdiv">
            <h1>LIST 1</h1>
              <ul>
               ...
             </ul>
             </div>

             <div class="footerdiv">
            <h1>LIST 2</h1>
              <ul>
               ...
             </ul>
             </div>

            <div class="footerdiv">
            <h1>LIST 3</h1>
              <ul>
               ...
             </ul>
             </div>

            <div class="footerdiv">
            <h1>LIST 4</h1>
              <ul>
               ...
             </ul>
             </div>

         </section>
     </footer>
```

and the css would just be:

```
div.footerdiv {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was the solution I also discover myself :)

Comment: @John23 lol yeah i saw that literally as soon as i posted this you commented that on the other answer with the same solution! great minds think alike :)